# How to handle inverse agonism when calculating bias?

Tags: medications, mathematics

Is there a standard way to compare an inverse agonist to an agonist in a bias calculation? The problem is that inverse agonists have negative efficacy, so you can't take the log to calculate RA... Would you only be able to compare different inverse agonists amongst themselves?